# Get Google app engine endpoints working in PHP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I get Google app engine endpoints working in PHP? Can I run python next to PHP? Is there a way to get it. I found this, but it was next to no help.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yue4X8rcGJU

I am wanting to get a restful API running on my AppEngine site and this looks like it would have been perfect.

I have tried messing with the app.yaml and making more than one.

Comment: Did you get any further in your attempts to get end points working with PHP runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Cloud Endpoints are only generally available on Java and Python AppEngine runtimes.
You can create [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/) to use different runtimes inside the same AppEngine application. Depending on your use case this can be overkill to create a python module just for having access to endpoints...